# Native Javascript doesn't append element on the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website built in Expression Engine. In the back-end there is a code snippet that takes care of a JavaScript request and build a page based on the request.

1. I have a HTML Page without head tag.
2. This page is without styling

Sample:

```
<div class="top-arrow"><p><!--- Rest of code --></p>
</div>
<!-- Html page continues-->
```

I have added the following code in my attempt and it doesnt seem to work.

```
var span = document.createElement("span"); //Test element
span.textContent = "A <span> element.";

var node = document.getElementsByClassName("top-arrow");
node.insertBefore(span);
```

Below is what I get:

> TypeError: node.insertBefore is not a function
>
> node.insertBefore(span);

How best can I append text before the div with plain JavaScript.

Comment: try to use `node[0].insertBefore(span);`

Answer (score 3):

> `getElementsByClassName` will return `array-like` node-list which does not have method `insertBefore`

*The [Node.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method inserts the specified node before the reference node as a child of the current node(If referenceNode is null, the newNode is inserted at the end of the list of child nodes)*

*Note:* `referenceNode` is not an *optional* argument, if there is no ant ref node, pass `null`

Try this:

```js
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.textContent = "A <span> element.";

var node = document.getElementsByClassName("top-arrow")[0];
//_____________________________________________________^^(Get the first element from collection)
node.insertBefore(span, null);
```

```html
<div class="top-arrow">
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("top-arrow")` will return a live `HTMLCollection`. You can use it like an array:

```
node = document.getElementsByClassName("top-arrow")[0];
```

Also, if you want the new node to appear *before* `top-arrow` you need to do:

```
node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
```

As it is `node` has no children, so there is no need to do `insertBefore`.

Even though your HTML code has no body and head, the browser will 'fix' your HTML and add one.

I would write your code like this:

```
var span = document.createElement("span"); //Test element
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("A <span> element."));

var node = document.getElementsByClassName("top-arrow")[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array containing nodes with class specified. If you want to insertBefore or append anything to it you need to specify index of an element in this array. Also, insertBefore requires two arguments in function call (elementToInsert, elemenBeforeWhichYouWantToInsert). So, something like this should work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('top-arrow')[0].insertBefore(element, beforeWhatToInsert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your input they are very informative. I have solved this without the need of manipulating my DOM element by simply copying the dynamic part of the page and actually creating a new template in the back-end of Expression Engine and my problem was solved.